# Baking from multires doesn't work on a face

Tags: sculpting, texture-baking, multiresolution

When baking normals from multires one of the faces (both of the sides since its a symmetrical mesh) remain blank.

What i checked:
-The face orientation is the same as the others
-The face has the same material as the others
-The face is connected to the mesh
-That part of the mesh is sculpted in the subdivided version

[image: Normal map]
[image: Face Direction]
[image: map applied]

Comment: hello could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

ok so to solve this i just had to ad a loop cut on the face that was not baking.